# Critical section issue using database

Tags: c#, sql-server, critical-section

I have a exe that runs under the task scheduler and is scheduled to run once a week. This exe is present on 2 different clone servers [Load balanced], Both scheduled to be executed on the same datetime.

This exe checks for a flag in one of the tables in the database and executes.....the problem is in any case only 1 server must execute the exe and not both....

So server 1 checks the flag and has to set it and then execute the exe.....so that when server 2 polls the flag, it realizes that the first has already executed and backs off.

Now my question is, how do I ensure that the server that checks the flag in the DB sets it so that the second server does not get the unset value....

Something like a critical section problem at the database

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has app locks designed specially for this type of problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

If you really want to update a table with your value, you can do the test and set in one (implicit) transaction:

Update flagstable set flag = 'server1' where flag is null